# Calculate product rate of previous day in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, measure

I have a sample dataset:

```
DATE:  11-01-2015,   12-01-2015,  13-01-2015            
SALE:  $120,                $0 ,         $100
```

In tableau I want if Today's sale is 0 as given above for 12-0-2015 then previous day sale should be considered as today's sale.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated field with this formula:

```
IF SUM([Sale])=0
THEN LOOKUP(SUM([Sale]),-1)
ELSE SUM([Sale])
END
```

And compute using Date.

Comment: Previous_Value(Sum([Sale])) does not do what you imply, though it might appear to work in some circumstances. Lookup(Sum([Sale], -1) would do what the poster asked - assuming you set the "compute using" setting appropriately -- compute using Date in this case. (Not trying to be a jerk, but Previous_Value is widely misunderstood - it does NOT evaluate the expression passed as an argument, positioned one value to the left)

Comment: Previous_Value(<some default value>) re-evaluates the whole enclosing calculation positioned one index lower in the current window/partition of query results. The argument is only used as a default value when you try to evaluate Previous_Value before the first position. Previous_Value() acts like a recursive call to the enclosing calculation - i.e. the code that included a call to Previous_Value(). Its as close as Tableau gets to letting you write a loop. You can use it to iterate over query results once you get how partitioning and addressing works in table calls

Answer (score 0):

```
IF FIRST() <> 0 AND SUM([Sale])=0 THEN LOOKUP(SUM([Sale]), -1)
ELSE SUM([Sale]) END
```

Setting Compute Using to Date

Checking First() in the condition handles the case when the first day had zero sales